# padding-top without float:left?

Tags: html, css

```
ul.menu_middle_inner li {
         display:inline;
         list-style:none outside none;
         padding:0 10px;
}
```

not sure if things are clear enough .. but for this piece of code, how do i use padding-top for this class?? unless i use float:left, padding-top:5px(say) doesnt work at all... I don want to use float:left..... hope i m clear with my question...

Comment: Why wouldn't padding-top work without float? Please post your html (and some more contextual css), I something else is actually the problem. At this moment though the padding-top is 0.

Comment: what browser are you testing in?  It seems to work in Chrome:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/zcqmU/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
display:inline;
```

Paddings are not applicable to inline elements.

You need to turn it into a block-level element. Remove this line and the list will return back to being a block-level object.

If you need it to contract to the width of its content, you need float. Alternatively, try `inline-block` (may not work in all browsers).

Comment: padding-left and padding-right work for `<span>`, and `<span>` is an inline element :)

Answer (score 0):

try specifying padding in one go, instead of adding another padding parameter. padding direction goes clockwise, so it starts with top like so:

```
padding: top right bottom left;
```

so if you want to add padding on top:

```
padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
```

that gives you 0 padding in the bottom. if you want to add to both top and bottom you can use shorthand:

```
padding: 5px 10px;
```

oh and you have to add display: block(or if inline-block);